# SCP and sshpass - Can't copy from remote source to local destination using script on PIs - debian11

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, scp, sshpass

I am struggling to copy files from a remote source to my local destination
I am using scp and I have tried adding sshpass to send the password

I have a script that copies from my local source to a remote destination which works:

`sudo sshpass -p "pi" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no pi@$VAR_IP ls /some_dir`

> this just connects to it without having to put in additional commands to accept the connection if it is the first time

`sudo sshpass -p "pi" scp /path_to_app/$VAR_APP pi@$VAR_IP:/home/pi/$VAR_APP/`

> this successfully copies from my local source to my remote destination

Now... Even though the scp documentation says I can scp remote source to local destination
I can't seem to get it to work, here is how I am trying to do it in a different script:

`sudo sshpass -p "pi" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no pi@$VAR_IP ls /some_dir`

> this is just to initialize not to have to accept connection, same as the last script

`sudo sshpass -p "pi" scp pi@$VAR_IP:/home/pi/$VAR_APP/logs/file /some_local_dir/`

> This gives me the error: `scp: /home/pi/App_Name/logs/file: No such file or directory`

> the path doesn't exist on local but does on remote, so it seems it is trying to find it locally instead of remotely, any ideas on this?

I looked at all the related posts about this and the man pages but can't find an answer to my specific case

I cannot do the cert key thing as I have too many sites, it would take forever

I saw in one of the posts someone tried it without sshpass, I tried it too like this:

`sudo scp pi:pi@$VAR_IP:/home/pi/$VAR_APP/logs/file /some_local_dir/`

> This gave me the error: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname pi: Name or service not known`
> I don't think it works like that so I didn't go further down that vein

I hope I gave enough info with clarity
any help would really be appreciated

thank you so much for your time and input

Answer (score 0):

You mention that this command is not working `sudo sshpass -p "pi" scp pi@$VAR_IP:/home/pi/$VAR_APP/logs/file /some_local_dir/`

Did you check this?
`sudo sshpass -p "pi" ssh pi@$VAR_IP 'ls -l /home/pi/$VAR_APP/logs/file /some_local_dir/'` to check the directory is exist

If that issue is still there, I recommend you to try `pssh` and `pscp` which are parallel ssh that could do the same thing as sshpass

Comment: Thank you Justin, I did try pscp and interestingly they have a -pw option
however, I did not manage to get that to work for me (gave me connection refused errors)

Fortunately I did find the answer: I needed to sudo both sshpass and scp individually

Thank you for your input, trying your advice put me on the right path, appreciate it thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it, for anyone that comes across this problem
Here is how I found the fix:

The file I was looking for was a root file but I was sshing as pi.

Even though I sudoed the script, and sudoed sshpass
That does not mean scp is sudo, so each command in a line needs its own sudo
eg:

`sudo sshpass -p "pi" scp pi@IP:/file /local_dir/`

This doesn't work because sshpass has sudo but scp does not, however

`sudo sshpass -p "pi" sudo scp pi@IP:/file /local_dir/`

This works perfectly because scp now has sudo rights